# What is the meaning of "Him up the road"?

Tags: meaning

Gus & Dave jogging, Dave stopped & met a guy who ready to start the car.

> Dave: Didn't you work at Harrisons afore it shut down? Ah! I thought I
>   clocked you! I were ont' floor with Gaz. **Him up the road**.

Comment: Could ulcer you give a bit more context? Knowing the source of this extract might give a better clue as to the dialect that is being spoken and the meaning.

Comment: The quote is from Full Monty.  A complete context is very important in this case.  The accepted answer is a reasonable guess given the sparse background info, but providing the complete back story would reveal a different nuance to "him up the road."

Comment: @Adam I would agree in that context I would think "Him up the road" means that Gaz lives in a house on the same road as the person talking.

Comment: @sarriesfan Gaz is standing just a little way up the road, waiting for Dave. The line before this one is Gaz yelling down to Dave, to hurry him along.  Dave ignores Gaz, and continues his conversation with Gus.  In the stage adaptation, they changed Gaz's name to _Jerry_ and rewrote this line as: _"You were on the floor with Jerry  - **That's him up the road.**"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very clearly dialect rather than standard English, and in this case, it's likely that the standard English rendering would be

Dave: Didn't you work at Harrisons before they shut down? Ah! I thought I recognized you! I was on the floor with Gaz [a nickname]. He's up the road.